# Multiple package database per haskell platform

Tags: haskell-platform

I am trying to install multiple haskell-platforms and I want them to refer to their own package database and not the one located in $HOME/.ghc directory.

I tried GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable but it didn't work. 
Also how do I stop other haskell-platforms from detecting the packages installed by previous haskell-platform installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current ghc package database setup now has per-ghc-version databases of packages, so no manual intervention is necessary.